# How to get max element in a string array by linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Consider I have an array like the following one:

```
string[] Files = {"NO. 1", "NO. 2", "NO. 3", "NO. 4", "NO. 5", "NO. 6", "NO. 7"};
```

I want to find the element with the maximum number. How can I do this by Linq queries in C#?

Comment: Read about linq `linq Select`, `int.Parse`, `linq Max`, `string.indexOf`, `string.Substring` :P

Comment: What do you mean with maximum number? Do you want to parse the number from the "NO. X" string, where X is the required number and select the string with the highest X?

Comment: If the string "NO." is a constant (i.e. it never changes), then just use "var highest = Files.OrderByDescending(x => x).First()".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using LINQ to objects (rather than to a database)... then this'll do it.

```
string[] Files = { "NO. 1", "NO. 2", "NO. 3", "NO. 4", "NO. 5", "NO. 6", "NO. 7" };
var max = Files.OrderByDescending(x => int.Parse(x.Replace("NO. ", ""))).First();
```

The exact string manipulation will of course change if your list is some way different to what you posted.

There may be more elegant LINQ functions you can use, but these are the ones I found.

Comment: The answer I originally posted was 
`var z = Files.Max(x => int.Parse(x.Replace("NO. ", "")));` which retrieves the max number, not the max element.

Comment: You can replace `Take(1).Single()` by `First()`.